# Load raster style from CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, style

I have a CSV file containing four columns: label, red, green and blue.
The label column contains all my possible raster values (from 0 - 100), and each red, green and blue columns contain the unique colour channel combination correspondent to each label.

I want to be able to import this CSV into QGIS as a style for different rasters - is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that a plugin is being developed to support a table of attributes to raster files.

Maybe this plugin covers what you need Table to Style you can see the description here https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/table2style/

This other plugin is another option RasterAttributeTable and the description https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RasterAttributeTable/

You can also do it with PyQGIS

Comment: The plugin Table to Style works perfectly! Thanks